# How to loop through value from 1 input field on dynamically added rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added below code to add rows on a button click using jQuery.
First rows last input field does contain username for the person logged in.
Now when I am clicking the Add button the following tr are coming empty and does not inherit the user name at all.

View

```html
<table id="dataTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th>Contact Name</th>
<th>Contact No</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
@if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
{
int j = 0;
foreach (var i in Model)
{
<tr style="border:1px solid black" class="data">
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].ContactName)</td>
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].ContactNo)</td>
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Email,new { @id="email"})</td>
<td>
@if (j > 0)
{
<a href="#" class="remove" id="delete">Remove</a>
}
</td>
</tr>
j++;
}
}
</table>
```

jQuery code to dynamically insert rows

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

   //1. Add new row
   $("#addNew").click(function () {
       var $tableBody = $("#dataTable");
       var $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last");
       var $trNew = $trLast.clone();

       var suffix = $trNew.find(':input:first').attr('name').match(/\d+/);
       $trNew.find("td:last").html('<a href="#" class="remove" id="delete">Remove</a>');
       $.each($trNew.find(':input'), function (i, val) {
           // Replaced Name
           var oldN = $(this).attr('name');
           var newN = oldN.replace('[' + suffix + ']', '[' + (parseInt(suffix) + 1) + ']');
           $(this).attr('name', newN);
           //Replaced value
           var type = $(this).attr('type');
           if (type.toLowerCase() == "text") {
               $(this).attr('value', '');
           }

          // If you have another Type then replace with default value
          $(this).removeClass("input-validation-error");
       });
       $trLast.after($trNew);

       // Re-assign Validation
       var form = $("form")
           .removeData("validator")
           .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
       $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
   });

   // 2. Remove
   $(document).on('click', '#delete', function () {
       $(this).parent().parent().remove();
   });
});
```

I tried an approach to first store the Email value in a variable and going back and copy the value into the input field for Email, which did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this on my own by using IList<> interface and for loop in the code.